# cin isn't grabbing from input file

Tags: c++, input, file-io, cin

I have the following code and input file. When trying to use cin, nothing seems to get put into "number" and the program just sits there until its killed. The string to poly function just separates the string into its two parts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct polynomial
{
    float numA;
    float numB;
};

polynomial stringToPoly(string input);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector<polynomial> Numbers;
    string number;
    polynomial polynumber;

    while (cin >> number)
    {                                                                                   
        polynumber = stringToPoly(number);
        Numbers.push_back(polynumber);
    }

}
polynomial stringToPoly (string input)
{
    polynomial polynumber;
    int negswitch = 1;
    string partA, partB;
    int i=0;

    while (input[i]!='x')
    {
        partA += input[i];
        i++
    }   
    i++; // to bypass the 'x' in the binomial

    while (input[i] <= input.size())
    {
         partB+= input[i];
         i++;
    }

    float a = strtof((partA).c_str(),0);
    float b = strtof((partB).c_str(),0);

    polynumber.numA = a;
    polynumber.numB = b;

    return polynumber;
}
```

Here is the input file that is given by the command line:

```
  25.4x+5.2
  -32.6x+13.7
  2.6x-9.7
  -16.1x+0
```

Comment: what about the stringToPoly function?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://ideone.com/FTZp38 Possibly something is going wrong in `stringToPoly`. Please edit your question to add a [mcve]

Comment: i updated the code to include this function. Right now, nothing is being inserted into "number" and that is my main problem.

Comment: Rethink what you are trying to accomplish with `input[i] <= input.size()`

Comment: the `i++` is not within the scope of either `while` loop. Both loops are infinite.

Comment: right now I'm not worried about the stringtopoly function, i know it has some flaws, i just need to know why cin isn't grabbing from the input file

Comment: It is grabbing. `stringtopoly` locks the program up in an infinite loop before it can grab a second input.

Comment: It isn't, when I added a check right at the beginning of the while loop, just a simple cout << number, it doesn't print anything. Its getting stuck on the cin

Comment: first ,the main function missing a }.second,the i++ is out the scope of while .

Comment: `cout << number` doesn't force an output flush and to save time, a program doesn't write data to IO until it has to or is forced to. Your message never made it to the screen. Try `cout << number << endl;` `endl`adds a line feed and forces the stream to write whatever it has stored up. Careful with `endl` under normal circumstances. Unnecessary IO writes are very expensive.

Comment: its still not working. and i fixed the stringtopoly function.

Comment: `while (input[i] <= input.size())` makes no sense. While the numerical value of a character in the string is less than the size of the string. This will most likely run off the end of the string and into unknown memory before it has a chance to exit.

Comment: The idea behind this part was to start at the char after the 'x' and go until the end of the string.

Comment: In that case, ask yourself, "What do I need to test is less than the size of the string to stay in this loop?"

Comment: aside from that problem, number is still empty after the in statement.I put a cout<<"here\n" right after the cin and that isn't even showing up

Comment: so by using gdb i figured out that even with the argument provided, it is still waiting for the user to type something

Comment: it works using redirection, so it must be something with the argument setup.

Comment: There is no end of file to standard in until the user says they are done. This is usually signaled by pressing ctrl+z or ctrl+d. You can also use a sentinel value like "exit". ie: `if (number == "exit") break;`